# Getting results from MySQL tables that have same calendar date as timestamp variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following date variable, which is converted to display as `Month, 10, 2012` in Arizona time:

```
$date = $_GET['date'];


$tzFromend = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'); 
$tzToend = new DateTimeZone('America/Phoenix'); 


    $dtend = new DateTime($date, $tzFromend); 
    $dtend->setTimezone($tzToend);


$dtend->format('F j, Y');
```

In the query below, `e.time` is a timestamp.  I would like to modify the query below to contain all values with the same calendar date as `$date` in Arizona time.

How could I do this?

```
$sqlStrend = "SELECT e.loginid, e.time, e.points, s.title
      FROM endorsements e
      JOIN submission s ON e.submissionid = s.submissionid
     WHERE e.loginid = '$idn' 
  ORDER BY e.time DESC
  LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$d = $dtend->format('c');

$sqlStrend = "SELECT e.loginid, e.time, e.points, s.title
  FROM endorsements e
  JOIN submission s ON e.submissionid = s.submissionid
 WHERE e.loginid = '$idn' AND DATE(e.time) = DATE($d)
 ORDER BY e.time DESC
 LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```